# Checking where a symbolic link points at in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, symbolic-link

In Windows 7, how can I check if a file is a symbolic link or not, if a folder is a junction or not, and how can I check where they are pointing at (in case they are symlink/junction). Both in Explorer and in Command line.

It's very important to have a way to do it from command line, in order to know how to duplicate symbolic links on another computer when you want to make an exact replica of a folder tree.

If I right click on a file and check "Properties", I can't find any indication that it's a symbolic link.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [dir command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) `dir /a` can do this:

```
2012-12-26  09:30 PM    <DIR>          .
2012-12-26  09:30 PM    <DIR>          ..
2012-12-26  09:30 PM                 0 a.txt
2012-12-26  09:30 PM    <SYMLINK>      link.txt [a.txt]
```

Alternatively, you can use Windows Explorer:

```
Right click column, More, Link Target
```

Comment: This doesn't work in windows 7 (Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601])

Comment: @gonzalezea yeah, it does. It worked with Windows 7 back in 2012 when I posted this, and it works now too

Comment: Perhaps not so obvious to new users, this is a command line solution. The user must open a command prompt, then change directory (using the CD command) to a directory containing a symbolic link, then type the DIR command and press the 'enter' key. Running the DIR command in the wrong directory is a common mistake. But understandable, unless you are sure which directory a symlink is in (not always obvious, as the Windows GUI does not explicitly tell you whether a particular directory contains any symlinks or junctions). Look for a shortcut that has the type _FILE FOLDER_ instead of _SHORTCUT_.

Comment: The link target field is empty on windows 7

Comment: from the command line you should type in `dir /a` then press Enter. If you do not include the /a, windows does not list junction points. You can try the difference between `dir` and `dir /a` on directory `\Users\YourUsername`

Comment: `dir /a` works, thank you. Windows Explorer option does not seem to work in Win 7, though. Maybe I didn't understand it.

Comment: @Paulus On Windows 10 `dir` shows symlinks to files and directories just fine, without `/a` (`<SYMLINK>` / `<SYMLINKD>`). But yes, it does not show `<JUNCTION>`-s. Note #1: you can use `dir /al` to exclusively list links/junctions ignoring all other files. Note #2: Explorer, being Explorer, shows link target incorrectly. If you have relative symlink like this: `..\..\..\foo\bar.txt` Explorer will just show the full absolute path, while command line will correctly show the relative path that is actually stored in the link.

Answer (score 6):

Copied from [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883892/batch-file-windows-cmd-exe-test-if-a-directory-is-a-link-symlink), I just used this line, and it works

`fsutil reparsepoint query "folder name" | find "Symbolic Link" >nul && echo symbolic link found || echo No symbolic link`

**Explanation**:

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753059.aspx) about FSUtil :
Performs tasks that are related to file allocation table (FAT) and NTFS file systems, such as managing reparse points, managing sparse files, or dismounting a volume. If it is used without parameters, fsutil displays a list of supported subcommands.

For our use, we just care that it outputs a line that has "Symbolic Link" in it, if it's symbolic, which we then `find`, and if `find` succeeds, we output one thing, if it doesn't, we output something else.

**Notes**:

- The quotes around the folder name are required if the path has spaces in it.
- It gives the same output whether the folder doesn't exist, or isn't a symlink, use with caution.

Answer (score 6):

Using PowerShell, on at least Windows OS, you can find symbolic-links in any given directory, such as the following:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\nodejs\bin\' | Where-Object {$_.LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink'}
```

A more concise alternative would be to use `Get-ChildItem`'s alias `ls`:

```
ls 'C:\nodejs' -Attributes ReparsePoint -Recurse
```

And you can get relevant information on a symbolic-link by doing any of the following:

Get the file item and output its **Target property**. Target being the "value" of the symbolic-link. In an addition, method or command signatures for creating symlinks when juxtaposing between operating systems, the arguments names of: 'target', 'path' and/or 'value' may hold different meanings than another method signature on a different OS.

```
E:\AIT> Get-Item -Path 'C:\nodejs\bin\ionic.cmd' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Target
E:\AIT\out\dependency_symlink.cmd
```

Get the file item and output its **LinkType property**. An item with a LinkType value of SymbolicLink means that its, well, symbolic.

```
E:\AIT> Get-Item -Path 'C:\nodejs\bin\ionic.cmd' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LinkType
SymbolicLink
```

Get the file item and output its **Mode property**. An item with `l` in the Mode value indicates that it is a symbolic-link.

```
E:\AIT> Get-Item -Path 'C:\nodejs\bin\ionic.cmd' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mode
-a---l
```

Get the file item and output its **Attributes property**. An item attributed with a ReparsePoint value *maybe* indicative to a symbolic-link.

```
E:\AIT> Get-Item -Path 'C:\nodejs\bin\ionic.cmd' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Attributes
Archive, ReparsePoint
```

Answer (score 3):

### To check the location of Symlinks and Junction Points in Windows 7 or Windows 10...

**Via Windows Explorer:**

1. **Open the parent folder** of the suspected symlink or junction point. (Note that symlinks and junction points get a shortcut icon applied in Windows 10 - not sure about Windows 7.)
2. In the top of the Explorer window, in the row of column names, right-click and select "More...".

[image]

3. Tick the box next to "Link Target" in the popup window that appears.

[image]

The path to the actual symlink location will be displayed in the Link target column that is added. Note that this only works for symlinks - not junction points:

[image]

---

**Via Command Prompt:**

1. Navigate to the parent folder of the suspected symlink or junction point.
2. Type `dir /a`.

A list of all files and folders will be displayed, including details of whether each is a symlink or junction point and where it points to:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `fsutil` to check if an item is a symbolic link or not. 
At first because errorlevel has errors, so sometimes, it stays to 0 and a real folder is viewed as a symbolic link. Errorlevel can not be trusted.

A problem with `find` is because `find "Symbolic Link"` is possible in English, but not in other languages.

The good way is to search from the attributes :

```
for %%i in ("%file_to_test%") do set attribute=%%~ai
set attribute=%attribute:~8,1%
if "%attribute%" == "l" (
    echo It's a symlink!
) else (
    echo Damned! It's real!
)
```

Attributes got with %a are "drahscotlep" and "l" is for symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cygwin bash script to save symlinks, 
add your favourite folders to first line

```
find c:/ C:/Users/$USERNAME/SendTo C:/Users/$USERNAME/Desktop \
      -maxdepth 2 -type l \
      -printf 'mklink\t/D\t"%p"\t"%l"\n' | \
  perl -pne '\
      s!/cygdrive/(\w)/!\1:/!g;\
      s,/a/,/%USERNAME%/,g;\
      1;' | \
  sort -f | uniq  > restore-links.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

all credits to [@SecurityAndPrivacyGuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11187266/securityandprivacyguru) , [cmd]

complete batch script/function that reads symlink{|s in folder} and outputs list with them and their target paths

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%~dp0"
set br=^


rem br;


set "pafIf=<<pafToSymlink|pafToFolder>>"
set "gIfZsymLink="
for /f "tokens=*" %%q in ('dir "!pafIf!" /al /b') do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%r in ('dir /al ^| findstr /i /c:"%%q"') do (
        set "gIfZsymLink=!gIfZsymLink!%%~fq>%%r!br!"
    )
)
set "gIfZsymLink=!gIfZsymLink:~0,-1!"
rem echo "!gIfZsymLink!"

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=>" %%q in ("!gIfZsymLink!") do (
    echo symlink: %%q , filepath: %%r
)


:scIn
rem endlocal
pause
rem exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use fsutil, you can use both technics to prevent failure from errolevel. (I use ver >nul to reset errorlevel)

```
:function_is_symlink_file_folder item_to_test result
rem 0 = Error
rem 1 = Symlink
rem 2 = File
rem 3 = Folder

:function_is_symlink_file_folder
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set item_to_test=!%~1!
    set /a result=0
    for %%i in ("%item_to_test%") do set attributes=%%~ai
    set attribute_1=%attributes:~0,1%
    set attribute_9=%attributes:~8,1%
    ver >nul
    fsutil reparsepoint query "%item_to_test%" >nul
    if %errorlevel% == 1 (
        if "%attribute_1%" == "d" (
            set /a result=3
        ) else (
            set /a result=2
        )
    ) else (
        if "%attribute_9%" == "l" (
            set /a result=1
        ) else (
            if "%attribute_1%" == "d" (
                set /a result=3
            ) else (
                set /a result=2
            )
        )
    )
    endlocal & set /a %~2=%result%
goto :eof
```